# Drush dl not working on Ubuntu with postgresql backend

Tags: drush

**modules can be added manually, but drush dl or drush en produce errors and will not download a module**

**database section from settings.php**

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'database' => 'drupal7',
    'username' => 'drupal7',
    'password' => 'secretpw',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '',
    'prefix' => ''
```

**also, when I run drush sql-cli it ask for a password**

**results of a module download attempt: "drush dl"**

```
root@list:/usr/share/ilterweb# drush dl admin_menu -vd 
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0 sec, 1.88 MB]                               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01 sec, 1.99 MB] [bootstrap]
Cache MISS cid: 6.5.0-alias-path--42baa7de58f511c1e70f7cbef941324c [0.01 sec, 2      [debug]
MB]
Cache HIT cid: 6.5.0-commandfiles-0-17d9338540482247f3d013b718aae478 [0.01 sec,      [debug]
2.01 MB]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.08 sec, 5.38 MB]                                        [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.13 sec, 6.24 MB]       [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 7.26 root directory at /usr/share/ilterweb [0.14 sec, 6.24 MB]   [notice]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.14 sec, 6.25 MB]       [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.14 sec, 6.25 MB]                [notice]
Cache HIT cid: 6.5.0-commandfiles-2-062e26fa8ebdd8c444d688ab9447c986 [0.14 sec,      [debug]
6.25 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.14 sec, 6.25  [bootstrap]
MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.16 sec, 6.27 MB]   [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.16 sec, 6.27 MB]               [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.18 sec, 6.78 MB]       [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 6.5.0-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.37 sec,     [debug]
16.57 MB]
Cache HIT cid: 6.5.0-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.37 sec,     [debug]
16.57 MB]
Cache HIT cid: 6.5.0-commandfiles-5-d366cec34f20f219c93d2cf7b993082d [0.37 sec,      [debug]
16.58 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_login() [0.37 sec, 16.57 MB]     [bootstrap]
Successfully logged into Drupal as Anonymous (uid=0) [0.38 sec, 16.68 MB]        [bootstrap]
Found command: pm-download (commandfile=pm) [0.38 sec, 16.68 MB]                 [bootstrap]
Loading version_control engine. [0.46 sec, 16.71 MB]                                [notice]
Loading package_handler engine. [0.46 sec, 16.72 MB]                                [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Loading release_info engine. [0.47 sec, 16.75 MB]                                   [notice]
Including /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/pm/download.pm.inc  [bootstrap]
[0.48 sec, 16.84 MB]
Calling hook drush_pm_download_validate [0.48 sec, 16.91 MB]                         [debug]
Returned from hook drush_pm_download_validate [0.48 sec, 16.91 MB]                   [debug]
Calling hook drush_pm_download [0.48 sec, 16.93 MB]                                  [debug]
Downloading release history from                                                    [notice]
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/admin_menu/7.x [0.48 sec, 16.93 MB]
Executing: wget --version
  GNU Wget 1.15 built on linux-gnu.

  +digest +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file +nls +ntlm +opie +ssl/openssl

  Wgetrc:
      /etc/wgetrc (system)
  Locale:
      /usr/share/locale
  Compile:
      gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/etc/wgetrc"
      -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/share/locale" -I. -I../../src -I../lib
      -I../../lib -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/usr/include -g -O2
      -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat
      -Werror=format-security -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall
  Link:
      gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat
      -Werror=format-security -DNO_SSLv2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall
      -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto
      -ldl -lz -lidn -luuid ftp-opie.o openssl.o http-ntlm.o
      ../lib/libgnu.a



  Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
  Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_filen1hmBh url for admin_menu/7.x
Undefined variable: xml updatexml.inc:475 [1.49 sec, 16.93 MB]                      [notice]
Could not download project status information from                               [error]
(url admin_menu/7.x [1.49 sec, 16.93 MB]
Could not download requested project(s). [1.49 sec, 16.93 MB]                    [error]
Returned from hook drush_pm_download [1.49 sec, 16.93 MB]                            [debug]
Command dispatch complete [1.49 sec, 16.9 MB]                                       [notice]
 Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec) 
 page   1.352      1      1351.72
Peak memory usage was 18.55 MB [1.49 sec, 16.91 MB]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `drush status` working?

If so, go to desire path like `sites/all/modules/contrib` & try `drush dl admin_menu`

I think drush expecting higher bootstrap level.

> If drush status it's not working, check your drush installation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get Postgres working with Drush is to set up a [pgpass file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html) in your home directory.

`$ cat $HOME/.pgpass
localhost:5432:*:user:secretpassword`

Replace 'user' with the user account that is calling Drush.  That should clear up your problems with sql-cli and pm-enable.

Your problem with pm-download is a separate issue.  When I run the command you show above, the key difference in my log output is:

`Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /private/tmp/download_fileoPH7NZ https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/admin_menu/7.x`

Note that your line has "url " where it should say "https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/".  Drush gets this information from the option --source.  Maybe you have define `$options['source'] = "url";` somewhere in one of your drushrc.php files?  If so, take that out, and it should behave correctly again.